# Missing 'In App Purchases' (IAPs)

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

This is a responce from Apple when I uploaded an *In App Purchases* build to *iTunes connect*.

Can any one say what I have to do.

> #### Missing IAPs
>
> We are unable to complete the review of your app since one or more of your In App Purchases have not been submitted for review.
>
> Specifically, did you upload the binary that contains IAP?
>
> Please be sure to take action and submit your In App Purchases AND upload a new binary in iTunes Connect. Learn more about submitting In App Purchases for review in the In-App Purchase Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect.
>
> Once you've submitted your In App Purchases and uploaded a new binary, we can proceed with your review.
>
> Note: Apps that offer In-App Purchase products that must be restorable are required to include a "Restore" feature. The following In-App Purchase types must be restorable:
>
> - non-consumable products
> - auto-renewing subscriptions
> - free subscriptions
>
> For more information, please see the section, Restoring Transactions, in the In-App Purchase Programming Guide.

Comment: They are saying either you haven't defined your in app purchases in iTunesConnect or that your binary doesn't offer an opportunity to purchase the in app purchases.

Answer (score 0):

I did not submit the **Edit Duration** and **Pricing In-App Purchase Details**.

Screenshot for Review (this information is filled out in itunes connect). Along with new binary I submitted to them. After these changes, Apple approve my app.

[image: Screenshot of iTunesConnect web site]